# Nonincreasing sequence of functions

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, analysis, sequence-of-function

Let $f_n:[a,b]\to[0,\infty)$ be a sequence of differentiable functions such that $\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n'(t)\leq 0$. The derivative is taken with respect to $t\in[a,b]$. Then is it possible to conclude that there exists a subsequence still denoted by $f_n$ such $\{f_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is nonincreasing with respect to $t$.

I think it is true, but cannot see how to prove.

Can someone please help, first of all if it is realy true? If so, some argument please.

Thanks.

Comment: $f_n(t) = \frac{1}{n}t~$?

Comment: But its fine for this sequence, since this is nonincreasing.

Comment: So what exactly is the question? You are mixing the requirements for $f_n$.

Comment: Hi, sorry. I understood your example, $f_n^{'}(t)=\frac{1}{n}\geq 0$. At least can we get $f_n$ nonincreasing upto a subsequence? I edited the question too. Thanks.

Comment: But this is nonincreasing in $t$, right?

Comment: Why is $f_n(t) = \frac{1}{n}t$ not a counterexample?

Comment: Is it not possible to prove by MVT?

Comment: Obviously not if there is a counterexample. If I understood your question correctöy then my functions $f_n$ are such a counterexample

Comment: Because $f_n(t)=\frac{t}{n}$ is nonincreasing in $t$. By nonincreasing, I meant $t_1\geq t_2$ imply $f_n(t_1)\leq f_n(t_2)$.

Comment: No. It is clearly increasing.

Comment: Thanks, so it is false. I guess it is true if the convergence is uniform, right?

Comment: It is false. It is still not true is convergence is uniform. My counterexample works again.

Comment: Hi, sorry again. I should have thought it. Any extra condition on $f_n$ for which the $f_n$ will be nonincreasing in $t$? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT:** Consider the following sequence of functions on [0,1]:

$$f_n(t)=-\Big(t-\frac{1}{n}\Big)^2$$

Comment: Hi, thanks. Please see the edited question. Can we at least get the nonincreasing property for $f_n$?